# Desplegar proyecto Maven en multiples instancias tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

soy nuevo en Maven. Estoy intentando desplegar un proyecto web hecho con Java y con Eclipse, pero necesito desplegarlo en 2 servidores distintos(tenemos balanceados los servidores).
Para ello he creado en el Pom 2 profiles donde tengo almacenada la url del servidor como una variable, y uso el plugin "tomcat7-maven-plugin" para desplegarlo. En la pantalla de "run configuration" del eclipse en "goals" pongo "clean install tomcat7:redeploy" y en "profiles" pongo "desarrollo1 desarrollo2" (que son los 2 profiles que creé en el pom).
Si ejecuto solo uno de ellos me funciona bien pero al poner los 2 solo me ejecuta el último que ponga. He probado a separarlos con espacio, con comas y con comillas y nada. ¿Qué hago mal? ¿hay otra forma mejor de hacer esto?
Un saludo y gracias.

[image: Imagen de la configuración usada]

Comment: lo que haces mal es no configurar el balanceo. Te recomiendo intentar con nginx y tomcat o usar apache http y mod_jk si es que debes deplegar en algun servidor de aplicaciones

Comment: Gracias Ruslan, el problema es que yo no tengo acceso a los servidores y no puedo hacer ningún tipo de cambio en este sentido.
¿No es posible con Maven y con el POM hacer esto que pido? desplegar en 2 servidores distintos de tomcat?
Esto mismo con Ant lo hacía de forma super sencilla

Comment: desplegar si, pero tus servidores ya deben estar configurados para hacer el balanceo. teoricamente basta con hacerte n perfiles donde n es la cantidad de despliegues que quieres y en cada perfil configurar tu plugin para un despliegue distinto.

Comment: Si, si el balanceado no es el tema, si eso funciona perfectamente. Es si es posible en una sola instrucción poder hacer 2 despliegues. De la forma que tú dices ya se hacerlo, es decir, tener 2 perfiles y ejecutar 2 veces llamando a cada perfil, pero lo que yo quiero es ahorrarme un paso. Quiero hacer una sola llamada y que se me despliegue en 2 sitios. Para ello había probado a llamar a los 2 perfiles separándolos por 1 espacio, tal como se puede ver en la imagen que adjunté, pero por lo que veo solo se puede llamar a un perfil cada vez. No se si con varios 'execution' será posible esto

Comment: Acabo de probar con el plugin del ant para maven "maven-antrun-plugin" y me ha funcionado, se ha desplegado en los 2 sitios. Yo quería hacerlo de una forma más "elegante" dejando ya de usar ant pero me ha sido imposible. Con los perfiles, solo se ejecuta uno aunque pongas varios (se ejecuta el último que pongas) y con "execution" no he probado ya que desconozco como se haría pero por lo poco que he leido quizás por ahí también se pueda, no se.

Comment: ya intentaste con `mvn clean install tocat7:redeploy -P desarrollo1,desarrollo2` o si es en powershell `mvn clean install tocat7:redeploy -P 'desarrollo1,desarrollo2'` (separar con comas)

Comment: Como puedes comprobar en la imagen que envié no lo hago por línea de comandos sino por la pantalla del eclipse de "run configurations" pero vamos que básicamente pongo lo mismo que dices pero en las casillas habilitadas a tal efecto, y no, no me funciona, solo ejecuta el último de los 2 profiles q pongo.

Comment: no es lo mismo, porque tu usas espacios y no comas como indica la documentacion

Comment: Si, tal y como puse en el primer mensaje "He probado a separarlos con espacio, con comas y con comillas y nada" asique si, si probé a separarlos de varias maneras con los mismos resultados.